# Starting session has failed. Unable to login

Tags: elementary-website

Io.elementary.greeter
Starting the session has failed

Details : Session Returned error code 1

Can someone please tell me why this is happening????? I can't login and there are so many projects I have on this that I need to use !!

I went into the command line and there was an ACPI error that kept on coming up saying

ACPI BIOS Error(bug): Could Not Resolve [_SB.IPPF._STA.POS1], AE_NOT_FOUND (psargs-330)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am facing the same issue. I do all of my coding work on eOS and it's all stuck there now.

This happened after the recent update to eOS 5.1.2

I can still boot into my Windows 10 (dual boot setup).

Do I have to reinstall it or is there some workaround?

Edit: Solved it by following the directions someone had posted somewhere else. Here's the solution: After being returned the error
Ctrl+Alt+F1
login with your username and password
"rm .Xauthority"
"sudo apt-get install pantheon-xsession-settings"
Ctrl+Alt+F7

Restart. Hope it helps

Comment: Because .Xauthority is owned by a root after update. chown username:group .Xauthority solves the issue. For example chown robert:robert .Xauthority

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

WORKAROUND

Edit /etc/default/grub 
and add in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line AFTER quiet word these:

vga=current loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log_priority=3

Next update grub :

sudo update-grub

Last thing is creating SYSCTL rule:

sudo bash -c "echo ‘kernel.printk = 3 3 3 3’ > /etc/sysctl.d/20-quiet-printk.conf’"

and reboot.

sudo systemctl reboot

This will just HIDE error msgs during boot, still exists in dmesg results.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: You should be running at least kernel version 4.18.0 (cat /proc/version*) because that included a fix that allows kernel to try to proceed even with errors while loading ACPI tables. Older kernel versions will stop loading the whole table in case of any error. And note that if older kernel version does not emit errors, it does not mean that it did work correctly - it probably just didn't even try to load those tables. Eventually it can work from 4.15. The other solution is to upgrade the BIOS. And the last one option is to disable ACPI in grub.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash pci=noacpi”

Comment: I didn't try updating the OS. But I did try disabling the ACPI in the Grub menu but that didnt do anything

Comment: Try to upgrade the OS
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade